# Убрать input из формы при AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

При выборе города форма отправляется аяксом и нам возращаются значения доступных служб доставки. Как отправлять её без некоторых инпутов?  Если на там присутсвует форма авторизации, то есть город не обрабатывается и приходят общие данные. Если её комментировать, то всё норм. Вот скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 var $this = $(this);
 var $form = {
    action: $this.attr('action'),
    post: {'ajax_key':'<?= md5('ajax_'.LICENSE_KEY)?>'}
 };
 //перебираем инпуты
 $.each($('input', $this), function(){
    $thisAuth = $(this).closest(".auth_form_holder").length; //если это блок авторизации, то не добавляем его в post
    if ($(this).attr('name') != undefined && !$thisAuth){
        if ($(this).attr('name').length) {
           $form.post[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        }
    }
 });
//submitForm();
$.ajax ({
        url: $form.action,
        data:  $form.post,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);

        }
});
```

$form.post содержит все нужные данные, но почему то всё равно неправильные данные приходят.

Answer (score 1):

На поля (инпуты), которые тебе не нужно считать или передавать, можешь накладывать атрибут `disabled="disabled"`. Тогда эти поля не будут передаваться при отправке формы.

**Короткий пример:**

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name1" value="name1"/>
    <input type="text" name="name2" value="name2"/>
    <input type="text" name="name3" value="name3" disabled="disabled" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

В данном случае сервер получит данные вида:

```
Array
(
    [name1] => name1
    [name2] => name2
)
```